# Install the magento 2.2.5 and no products or examples

Tags: installation, magento-2.2.5

I just installed magento 2.2.5 but to my surprise I have no products example, an empty homepage and nothing to test effectively is this normal?

On the home page I have "CMS homepage content goes here."
thank you in advance

Comment: Have you installed the sample data? In magenot download page are offered two versions, one WITH sample data and othe WITHOUT it.

Comment: Indeed it is that I took the version of the github, it must be without examples ...
I made a wget https://github.com/magento/magento2/archive/2.2.5.zip that's why
But is there a link to make a wget with the version that contains examples?
Thank you very much !

Comment: Look this: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/install/sample-data-after-magento.html, sample data is a magento 2 module, so it is not so dificult to install it.

Answer (score 0):

Per IpFranz's comment, you can download a zip with the full sample data included in the install from the Magento site: https://magento.com/tech-resources/download?icid=topnav

[image]

But i actually don't like doing it this way. The installer takes a long time and there can be issue with php timing out during the install. To avoid that, I install without the sample data and then use the CLI to install it after. Since you already have the site installed, this would be the best option (why install magento twice).

To start, you will need to get your id keys from magento, this can be found on your magento account. Got to `My Account -> Marketplace -> Your name -> My Profile`. From here you can copy the keys or create new ones.

You will then have to copy the `auth.json.sample` to be `auth.json` in the root of your magento install. In this file you will see a place to put your keys.

Then in your terminal you can run `php bin/magento sampledata:deploy`. This will pull in the needed data. It might take a little time, so if php get stuck for you, you can run the command `php -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento sampledata:deploy`. This will disable the memory limits for php.

After that is done, you need to run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`. Again, this might take a minute, so you can use `php -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento setup:upgrade` if php times out.

After that run, you are done. The sample data is installed on your site.

Comment: I tried the manipulation but I have this error - Potential causes:
- A typo in the package name
- The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
see <https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability> for more details.

Comment: This is unlikely related to the install of sample data. You are installing 2.2.5, what else are you installing with that? what 3rd party modules or themes?